# What's different between PlotView and Plot?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, oxyplot

I've seen two chart usages, `PlotView` and `Plot`.

If I use `PlotView`, I can use `Model="{Binding MyModel}"` only, I can't set other binding like source. I can't implement MVVM.

But if I use `Plot`, I can do any binding, and many sub-control setting in xaml likes `series`, `axes`, and so on.

May I know what's different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods are right, and both respect MVVM pattern. I think the only difference between both is this, as the creator(Oystein Bjorke) said:

> The `PlotView` component is now similar on all platforms, it contains
>   only `Model` and `Controller` properties. The `Plot` control let you
>   define axes, series, annotations etc. and this should only be
>   available in XAML-based platforms.

link: http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topics/240-cant-define-axes-in-xaml/

As a personal opinion, at first I used the `Plot` component, but then I had a problem with it: If you want to import the plot, you have to first create the view. Then I switched to `PlotView` component and the import worked ok without the view being created.